# How to save username and password in browser when used in Windows 10 Kiosk mode?

Tags: browser, passwords, kiosk-mode

I'm running kiosk mode on windows 10. It launches edge with a preconfigured website.
This website requires authentication, but I don't want to share credential to users, so I'm looking for a way to save credential in the browser. How can I do this?
Any other alternatives?

Thanks

I tried looking for documentation to store in windows registry without success.